# Implementing getOrCreate method async issue

Tags: javascript, asynchronous, promise

I have a class that encapsulate communication with a server
and it has a getOrCreate method to create a ShoppingCart resource in the server (I am using firebase, but my question is for all kind of server implementations)

Once the application is loaded in the client (I am using angular but again it does not matter for this question), two different components (areas of the screen) get the service class injected to them (it is a singleton) and they call a method getOrCreateCart()
This method should check in the localStorage if a cartId exists and if so return it. Otherwise, it should create it with an async call to the server.
The issue is that if both components call this method at the same time, with the lack of locking mechanisme, I can not block the second operation until the first one is completed and on the second time return the cartId from the localStrogate instead of creating another resource in the database

Checking if cartId already exists in the database is not an option, since the cartId is generated upon request to the server.

A little bit of code to make things more clear:

```
private async getOrCreateCartId() {
    let cartId = localStorage.getItem('cartId');
    if (cartId) return cartId;

    let newCartId = await this.create();
    localStorage.setItem('cartId', newCartId);
    return newCartId;
  }

 // Returns a promise with the new created id
 private create() {
    return this.db.list('/shopping-carts/').push({
      dateCreated: new Date().getTime()
    });
  }
```

Comment: A locking mechanism is not necessary. Arrange for the first call to `getOrCreateCart()` to cache and return a promise, which is returned in response to any subsequent calls. It doesn't matter whether subsequent calls occur before or after the promise has settled; the result (or error) will be delivered sooner or later.

Comment: @Roamer-1888 - Thank you so much! I have figured it out based on what you wrote. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Thanks to Roamer-1888 I've figured it out

This is my solution:

1. Cache the promise that returns from the create() method
2. For all subsequent calls, return this promise so when the result will arrive from the server, all the returned promises will be invoked
3. Before returning the promise, I call then and transform the value from the server to a simple string that I am interested in.

I ended up with this code:

```
private getOrCreateCartId() {
    let cartId = localStorage.getItem('cartId');
    if (cartId) return Promise.resolve(cartId);

    if (this.createPromise) return this.createPromise.then(result => result.key);

    this.createPromise = this.create();
    this.createPromise.then(result => {
      localStorage.setItem('cartId', result.key);
    })
    return this.createPromise.then(result => result.key);
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

Congratulations on figuring it out.

Here's what I ended up with, starting with an emulation of your singleton :

```
// singleton FOO
const FOO = (function() {
    var cartId = localStorage.getItem('cartId'); // cache, initialised from localStorage

    async function getOrCreateCartId() {
        if (!cartId) {
            cartId = create(); // cache promise
            localStorage.setItem('cartId', await cartId);
        }
        return cartId;
    }

    // Returns a promise with the new created id
    function create() {
        return new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
            setTimeout(() => {
                resolve(Date.now());
            }, 2000);
        });
    }
    return {
        'getOrCreateCartId': getOrCreateCartId
    };
}());
```

*At first glance, you would think `getOrCreateCartId()` is synchronous but that's an affect of async/await, which allow async code to be structured almost identically to sync code.*

And here are two rapid-fire calls to `FOO.getOrCreateCartId()`

```
// call from component 1
FOO.getOrCreateCartId().then(function(cartId) {
    console.log(cartId);
});
// call from component 2
FOO.getOrCreateCartId().then(function(cartId) {
    console.log(cartId);
});
```

The console will log the same cartId twice even if the call from component 1 needs to call `create()`.

[DEMO](https://jsfiddle.net/c4doqq5o/1/): I included a `.clear()` method so you can play around with it and convice yourself it works as it should.